# French language pack with email templates for 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, localisation, email-translation, language-package

I am looking for a recent language pack for Magento 1.9 with the email template files.

I came across this: https://github.com/versedi/Magento-Locales which is a collection of translations from the old Magento site. It has French translations but not the email templates.

There is also this one: https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/french-france-language-pack-for-magento-traduction-francaise.html Which is for 1.7 so it doesn't have the newest template files needed for 1.9.

Anyone who does know where to get it?

Answer (score 1):

Look at this one, it's compatible with all 1.9 versions http://www.bkm.uno/services-additionnels/magento-pack-fr-1-9-1.html

Comment: Yes, I hope too ;)